# Long-term, on-premise monitoring of Netty

Tags: playframework, netty, monitoring

We are currently using Play Framework with Netty for a new project. One thing we have to solve is to setup an solution for long-term monitoring (day, week, year etc) in production. New Relic seems to have support for Play 2, but we want to use an on-premise (not cloud-based/remote) solution.

Some things we would like to monitor:

- Heap usage
- Garbage Collection times and occurrences
- CPU
- Number of active threads
- Response times
- Requests per minute
- Bytes per minute (up/down)

Other things we value:

- Easy setup
- We would prefer that the disk usage will not "explode" when server activity gets high (RRD format solves that, but we are open to databases/other formats too).

In other projects (with Tomcat), we have used JavaMelody for monitoring and are happy with that, but JavaMelody works only in a container. We could use play2war to deploy our Play application in Tomcat and continue with that approach, but using Netty with Play seems like the recommended and most supported way to go.

Do you have any on-premise monitoring solutions to recommend for Netty?

Answer (score 0):

[Kamon](http://kamon.io/introduction/get-started/) is designed aslo for akka actors. Play is also supported.

For [Mockito](http://mockito.org) there is option to write own plugin for web monitoring but that is quite big effort.

Ad hoc you can also use JMC (Java Mission Control) and store historic data but it is not designed for easy long-term monitoring. It is present with JDK and almost no configuration is needed.